# Custom route not working | Codeigniter Routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, url-routing

I am working on an API via which I embed images of country flags on my website & several others.

I am taking in 3 parameters i.e

1. Country (Name of Country - ISO Code or Full Name)
2. Size (Dimension of Image)
3. Type (Styles like flat flag, shiny round flag etc...)

Now, have everything setup correctly but stuck in handling URI.

```
Controller -> flags.php
Function -> index()
```

**What I have now is :**

```
http://imageserver.com/flags?country=india&size=64&style=round
```

**What I want**

```
http://imageserver.com/flag/india/64/round
```

I went through some articles and made this route  but all of them **failed**

```
$route['flag/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = "welcome/index/country/$1/size/$2/style/$3";
$route['flag/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = "welcome/index/$1/$2/$3";
$route['flag/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = "welcome/index?country=$1&size=$2&style=$3";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also been having trouble with routes while writing my custom cms. Reading through your question, I see a couple issues that might very well be the answer you are looking for.

For starters, let's look at the routes you have tried:

```
$route['flag/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = "welcome/index/country/$1/size/$2/style/$3";
$route['flag/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = "welcome/index/$1/$2/$3";
$route['flag/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = "welcome/index?country=$1&size=$2&style=$3";
```

If you want to run the index method from your flags class, which it looks like you do, you don't want to route to the welcome class at all. Currently, however, you are. Your routes should look like:

```
$route['flag/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = "flags/index";
```

That way, Codeigniter will run the index method from your flags class. You don't have to worry about the country, size, or style/type in the route. The best option there would be to use the URI segment function like this:

```
$country = $this->uri->segment(2); //this would return India as per your uri example.
$size = $this->uri->segment(3); //this would return 64 as per your uri example.
$style = $this->uri->segment(4); //this would return round as per your uri example.
```

You could then use those variables to query your database and get the correct flag or whatever else you need to do with them.

So to restate my answer with a little more explanation as to why:

The routes you have currently are running the welcome controller/class and the index function/method of that controller/class. This, obviously, is not what you want. So you need to make sure your routes are pointing to the correct controller and function like I did above. The extra segments of the URI don't need to be in your route declaration, so you would then just use the uri_segment() function to get the value of each segment and do what you need with them.

I hope this helps you. I may not have found an answer for my problem, but at least I could provide an answer for someone else. If this seems confusing to you, check out the user guide at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide. The main links you need for this are:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

and

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Let me know if you need more help or if this helped solve your problem.